# How do you change the Eclipse IDE's color theme for this problem?

Tags: android, eclipse

While setting up my Eclipse IDE it seems that I don't know how to change the background color of this Java-assisted search:

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

That's a tricky one!

These are the marked occurrences. You change them in the preferences, under General → Editors → Text Editors → Annotations, and select Occurrences from the list.

[image]

Comment: Sure. So, mark it as the correct answer by using the V sign...

Answer (score 0):

This thread might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96981/color-themes-for-eclipse

Comment: thanks for the help. i applied those themes and it looks great. 

but i still dunno which one affects the problem i have